# Netlogo: create subset of turtles to use later

Tags: social-networking, netlogo

I'm constructing a model to research opinion dynamics given certain network structures. In the model, there is a hypothetical 'dictator' who can hand out resources (or 'bribes') to certain nodes in the network. Currently, the dictator has three strategies: 1) handing out bribes to the nodes in the network with the most positive opinion. 2) handing out bribes to the nodes in the network with the most links. And 3) handing out bribes to a random set of N nodes.

I got strategy 1 and 2 working correctly, but can't get 3 to work. Currently, the procedure looks like this

```
to go

  handout-bribes
  include-lpr
  update-motivation
  update-participation
  ask nodes [update-look-of-nodes]

      tick
    end

 ;;; Bribes are handed out either to the top N nodes with the most positive motivation, the top N nodes with the most ties, or randomly
to handout-bribes
  if strategy-of-dictator = "targeted-opinion" [
  ask max-n-of (num-nodes * percentage-receiving-bribes)  nodes [( - total-motivation) ] [set bribes (bribes + height-of-bribes)]]
  if strategy-of-dictator = "targeted-ties" [
    ask max-n-of (num-nodes * percentage-receiving-bribes)  nodes [count my-links] [set bribes (bribes + height-of-bribes)]]
  if strategy-of-dictator = "random" [
    ask n-of (num-nodes * percentage-receiving-bribes)  nodes [set bribes (bribes + height-of-bribes)]]
end
```

With this code a new random group of nodes to receive bribes is chosen each tick. What I want however, is that a the start of the procedure a group of N nodes is chosen who will receive bribes after each tick. How should I code this? I was thinking about creating a subset of nodes at setup, and calling these in the procedure. But I got no clue how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a global variable; set it to an agentset during setup.  (You can use `n-of` to create this agent set.)

Comment: That worked. Thanks!